# how to install healthcheck module in nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, healthcheck

I have installed nginx 1.10.0 in ubuntu and setup Load balance concept. Now, setup 2 server I need to add Health check module to chenck health status of our server.

```
  root@server:/usr/sbin# nginx -v
  nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

I read  about this documents  https://github.com/cep21/healthcheck_nginx_upstreams

this docmetn say:

```
           ==INSTALL==
    # Similar to the upstream_hash module

    cd nginx-0.7.62 # or whatever
    patch -p1 < /path/to/this/directory/nginx.patch
    ./configure --add-module=/path/to/this/directory
    make
    make install
```

I Instlled Nginx using cmd not a manually installed

cmd : apt-get install nginx

I dont know where nginx instlled , by default /usr/local/nginx. but no directory is there.[Reference](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/)

Suggest me How to install and setup  health check plugin in nginx

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the nginx module [ngx_http_upstream_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) will do what you want. It has [health checks](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#health_check) for the backends too. You will probably find that your Distro supplied nginx has all of this available.

Comment: > Dynamically configurable group with periodic health checks is available as part of our **commercial subscription**

Answer (score 0):

I bet them you are required to recompile the nginx with the health check module rather than installing the official one.